# To login to Steam need a RSA key. I have created a post request with HttpClient from java 11 ot get the key but it returns Body : {"success":false}

Tags: java, httpclient, steam

I am trying to create steam bot with java. I have the following code that posts to steam :

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
        String data = "{\"username\" : " + "\"" + USERNAME + "\"}";

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey"))
                .headers("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0", "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(data))
                .build();

        try{
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println("Body : " + response.body());
            System.out.println("StatusCode : " + response.statusCode());

        }
        catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("IOException : " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

It returns the following :

```
(POST https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey) 200
Body : {"success":false}
StatusCode : 200
```

I have done this with python using the Requests and it works. Following is code that works with python :

```
import requests;

print(requests.post("https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey/", params={"username": "AdwaitBot"}).content)
```

I dont understand what is the problem with my java code. Any help or advice will be appreciated.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: The parameters should be in the URL (URL Parameters), not in the body of your POST-Request.
The requests module in python would uses the parameter ```data``` if you'd send it in the body

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a method to add it to the url? An example will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` in your python code means request params in URI rather than the request body. The actual request you make in python is `POST https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey/?username=AdwaitBot`
In java, you should form your URI accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it works. Thanks for the fast response. I dont know how request send to servers work. Could you please help me with some resource that explains the working?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any specific resources, but I think you will get a lot of info from google. Search for something like "HTTP protocol explained". As for the URI parts, wikipedia has a good article about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier